# pdfcomment highlight doesn't work

Tags: hyperref, latexmk, comments, pdfcomment, annotations

I am using MikTex 2.9. I would like my text to be highlighted and I would like a comment to it. But my MWE below doesnot work.PLease help

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\usepackage[author={Max Schlepzig}]{pdfcomment}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{This highlighted Text Has Tool Tip With Hyperlink.}{Highlight}

\end{document}
```

Output of above code is just plain text [image]

Answer (score 6):

Load `lastpage` after `pdfcomment`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[author={Max Schlezpig}]{pdfcomment}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage}% 
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{This highlighted Text Has Tool Tip With Hyperlink.}{Highlight}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A bit late, but I'm having the same problem with some PDF viewers but not with others, with a minimum working example, not even using lastpage. Different viewers seem to handle comments differently.